# How to check if a multidimensional array key is in an array more than once?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multi array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [title] => f2 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [title] => f2 
        ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [title] => f3 
        ) 
)
```

I just want to check, if a key (represented by `$item`) is in the array more than once, so in my case 'f2' is in it more than once.

I tried it using `in_array`, but it didn't work with multi arrays.

Then I tried this:

```
$item='f2';
$array_count = array_count_values($titles);
if (array_key_exists($item, $array_count) && ($array_count[$item] > 1))
{
    echo 'more than once';

}
```

but this is still not working.

Comment: This is what you are looking for $onlyArrayWithTitles = array_column($item, 'title');

Comment: If you have warnings/errors showing, you would get `PHP Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) can be used:

```
 $arr = [
  [
    'title' => 'f2'
  ],

  [
    'title' => 'f2'
  ],

  [
    'title' => 'f3'
  ]
];

$counts = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'title'));

print_r($counts);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [f2] => 2
    [f3] => 1
)
```

Once you have the total count, you can simply do:

```
if (($counts[$item] ?? 0) > 1) {
    // do action
}
```

**Reading Material**

[Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: May I suggest `if (($counts[$item]??0) > 1)` in case the item does not exist in the list.

Comment: @Script47 No worries, it's only a minor edit but thank you. +1 for the solution

Comment: @NigelRen absolutely, that would be the best approach, I was going under the assumption that OP 100% knew the key would exist.

Comment: @NigelRen  it's new feature introduce in php 7, so need to add a note that if OP have older version then use `isset()` or `!empty()`

Comment: @Script47  it's new feature introduce in php 7, so need to add a note that if OP have older version then use `isset()` or `!empty()`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie the **Reading Material** should cover that as it links directly to the PHP 7 release notes.

Comment: the solution with array_column works for me, Thanks @Script47 for a brilliant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Loop and count, bail if you've already seen your pair:

```
<?php
$items =
[
    ['letter'=>'a'],
    ['letter'=>'a'],
    ['letter'=>'c']
];

$n = 0; $result = false;
foreach($items as $item) {
    if(($item['letter'] ?? null) == 'a' && $n++) {
        $result = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter your items and see if the count is greater than 1:

```
<?php

$items =
[
    ['letter'=>'a'],
    ['letter'=>'a'],
    ['letter'=>'c']
];

var_dump(count(array_filter($items, function($item) {
    return ($item['letter'] ?? null) == 'a';
})) > 1);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```